# Bootstrap navlinks padding issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Issue with navlinks padding in "sm" screen size. when im trying to write mediaquery for "sm" it effects both in "lg" and "md". 
   http://jsfiddle.net/L1ozsu2n/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">              
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-push-9 col-md-3 col-md-push-9 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9"> 
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right " role="search"> 
            <div class="form-group form_search">
              <input type="text" class=" search_box" placeholder="SEARCH"/>
            </div>
          </form>   
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-pull-3 col-md-9 col-md-pull-3 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">                    
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WOMEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">KIDS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GOODSALE</a></li>
          </ul>                          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>                  
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how the menu on the right is up against the top of the div, instead of vertically centered?

Remove the "navbar-header" class from the fourth div.

Comment: No that last link on menu comes down on sm screen size.

Answer (score 0):

after nav, use .container-fluid instead of container.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
```

Comment: It works almost fine. still it breaks at some point. anyhow i finally figured it out by writing mediaQuery.

Comment: at what point it is breaking? can you mention it??? i want to know what's wrong with my answer and if not why i am not getting a correct answer tick or atleast an upvote. Thank you.